# Issues with resolving style variables in an Angular project

Tags: angular, sass

I'm encountering an issue with resolving style variables in my Angular project. Here's the relevant code:

_stylevariable.scss:

```
:root {
  .tenant-a {
    --primary-color: #3E3C90;
  }
}
:root {
  .tenant-b {
    --primary-color: #ffffff;
  }
}

$primary-color: var(--primary-color);
```

Style.css:

```
@import "./_stylevariable";
.my-class {
  color: $primary-color;
}
```

I'm using the $primary-color variable in my SCSS, but it's not getting resolved consistently across my page. Some places it works, while in others the color class doesn't get applied correctly.

I suspect that there might be an issue with variable scoping, but I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this. I've tried checking for overrides of --primary-color and ensuring that the CSS is being properly compiled and loaded, but I'm still having trouble.

When I inspect the browser style its showing color: var(--primary-color) with unresolved color where its not working;  but where its working I can see in the browser with hyperlink to the variable with the resolved color coding.

In angular I am trying to implement dynamic styling and in app.component.ts class

```
 @HostBinding('class') get hostClasses() {
    return this.themeService.getTheme();
  }
```

Has anyone encountered a similar issue before? Any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

I tried below code but still its not working in some pages (I have encountered so far in the modal pop up)

```
:root {
  --primary-color-tenant-a: #3E3C90;
  --primary-color-tenant-b: #ffffff;
}

.tenant-a {
  --primary-color: var(--primary-color-tenant-a);
}

.tenant-b {
  --primary-color: var(--primary-color-tenant-b);
}

$primary-color: var(--primary-color);
```